# Are bounty points deducted on account deletion?

Tags: support

If I give bounty points for a question and then I delete my account in the future will those bounty points be lost by the answerer when my account is deleted ?

Comment: It is curious you are asking this since you’ve offered zero bounties so far.

Comment: Not sure in what way the two questions are related. Your concern appears to be about bounty points after an account deletion.

Comment: Well, the lack of bounties on your account is a matter of fact, not a personal impression. Anyway no problem, just a curiosity.

Comment: @user3850720 Your curiosity is noted. Thank you.

Comment: @NigelJ I hope you don't delete your account, you're a significant contributor.

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime How kind of you to say so, sir. No, I don't intend to. It was a hypothetical question - made out of curiosity :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, bounties remain: they just get transferred to the [Community user](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=bounties&sort=offered). This is how Community has those "83 Offered bounties for 10,650 reputation".

Reference: [employee's post on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89614).